# When to detach tensor used for indexing in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to index a `torch.Tensor` and want some advice about **when** I should detach the tensor corresponding to indices to slice from another `torch.Tensor`

```
prob: torch.Tensor # (float32)
label: torch.Tensor # (int32)

index = torch.arange(label.numel()).reshape(label.shape)
index = index * prob.shape[-1] + label
return torch.take(prob, index)
```

Where `prob` and `label` are tensors whose gradients should be preserved.  I simply want to know when to detach `index` considering I use `label` to compute the indices to take from `prob`.

I was thinking about changing the last line to

```
return torch.take(prob, index.detach())
```

but I do not know how this interacts with the fact that `label` is used earlier in the computation to compute `index`.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter because the gradient cannot pass through `index` anyway. It is non-differentiable with respect to the index.